# Having issue while connecting NodeJS with SQL

Tags: node.js

since 2 weeks I am trying to connect Microsoft SQL server with NodeJS. Please help me out with this

Am available on Instagram : **shaziyali8**

*Thanks in advance*

## Here is my Code#

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "HP\SQLEXPRESS", // I tried things such as : localhost, Id address: 127.0.0.1,  . (a dot)
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "testEmp",
//   port: 8889,
});
// console.log(connection);

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("connect");
  }
});
```

## Got error

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND HPSQLEXPRESS
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (F:\NodeJs\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (F:\NodeJs\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (F:\NodeJs\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\NodeJs\MySql\index.js:13:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'HPSQLEXPRESS',
  fatal: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL server but you are using a MySQL client npm package for the connection. The correct package to connect to a MSSQL server in Node.js is [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

Install this and check if the connection issue still persists. Also, if the MSSQL server is on your local then using `localhost` as host name with correct port number would work most of the time.

There are also `Connection Strings` that you can use to connect to the MSSQL server.
See the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)